# Free Pascal to Delphi conversion - Generic T default parameters

Tags: delphi, migration, freepascal

I'm trying to convert some Free Pascal code to compile with Delphi 10.2.

The Free Pascal code is structured like this:

```
generic TVolume<T> = class(TObject)
    // T has to be a numerical/float type
    constructor Create(pSizeX, pSizeY, pDepth: integer; c: T = 0);
    constructor Create(Original: TBits; pFalse: T = -0.5; pTrue: T = +0.5);
```

Delphi doesn't like this: `E2268: Parameters of this type cannot have default values`

I think the reason is simply that the Delphi compiler doesn't want to make assumptions of what type T might be, so it refuses to compile this. This point goes to FPC I'd say.

To workaround this, I most likely have to create a bunch of `overload` methods:

```
TVolume<T> = class(TObject)
    constructor Create(pSizeX, pSizeY, pDepth: integer); overload;
    constructor Create(pSizeX, pSizeY, pDepth: integer; c: T); overload;

    constructor Create(Original: TBits); overload;
    constructor Create(Original: TBits; pFalse: T); overload;
    constructor Create(Original: TBits; pFalse: T; pTrue: T); overload;
```

But I still wonder if there is a way a to do this in Delphi, which I'm not aware of yet?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to this question is:

> **No**, there is no way to pass default parameters to a Generic type `T` in Delphi, because the type of `T` is not known at the time of declaration. And since Delphi is a single-pass compiler, it does not allow this.

*Free Pascal* implements a [2-pass processing of Generics](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics#Other_Points). Thats why it can delay the code generation for a Generic until it encounters a specialization at implementation.

In this specific case, we discovered that a Generic declaration of `TVolume` is not even required anyway. In the entire Free Pascal project, `TVolume<T>` is implemented only once as `TNNetVolume = class (specialize TVolume<TNeuralFloat>)`. `TNeuralFloat` is of type `Single`. So the Generic declaration of `TVolume<T>` can be changed to `TVolume` and all references of `T` can be replaced with `TNeuralFloat`. This works and can be compiled in Delphi.

Thanks to [Rudy Velthuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) , [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) and [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) for their help and contribution to sort this out. :)